# Modify autoincrement column to global autoincrement column

Tags: database, sybase, auto-increment

Our company uses Sybase and we are planning on setting up a Mobilink system (data replication system). We therefore need to change from using autoincrement columns to global autoincrememnt columns.

My question is what steps do I need to take to get this working properly. There is already thousands of rows of data that used the regular autoincrement default.

I'm thinking I need to create a new column with a default of global autoincrement, fill it with data (number(*)), switch the PK to it, drop the old FK's, drop the old column, rename the new column to the old one, then re-apply the FK's.

Is there an easier way to accomplish what I need here?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's generally the way to go about it.  But there are some specific statements you make that cause me concern.  Also the sequence.  I am not sure of your experience level, the terms you use may or may not be accurate.

For each table ...

> *... switch the PK to it*

What about the FK values in the child tables ? Or do you mean you will change them as well ?

> *... drop the old FK's*

Ok, that's the constraint.

> *... drop the old column, rename the new column to the old one, then re-apply the FK's.*

What exactly do you mean by that ? Add the FK constraint back in ?  That won't change the **existing** data, it will apply to any **new** rows added.

Hope you see what I mean by *the sequence of your tasks is suspect*.  Before you drop the old_PK_column in the parent, you need to:

1. Add the dropped FK constraints in each child table.
2. For each child table: UPDATE all the FK values to the new_PK_column.
3. Then drop the old_PK_column.

Comment: your comments at the end (the 1,2,3) are what I was saying in other terminology. thanks! will give you a checkmark :)

Comment: @numone. Thanks! Any further questions, please post.

Answer (score 1):

you're just changing the way PK values are generated, so it's enough to:

```
ALTER TABLE <table>
  modify <column> default global autoincrement (1000000);
```

to use a partition size of 1,000,0000

Also make sure you set the global database identifier in each db, for example:

```
SET OPTION PUBLIC.global_database_id = 10;
```

So the next PK that will be generated is 10,000,001